# In React, how to prevent a component's CSS import from applying to the entire app?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I'm using [facebook's create-react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) for my application:

In my Login.js container, I am importing CSS like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../styles/users/Login.css'
const Login = () => {
....
```

The problem is the Login.css styles are being applied to my entire application... for example, if Login.css has:

```
body {
    background:Red ;
}
```

The entire app would have a body of background: Red; Even outside of the Login container.

What I expected/want is for a CSS import within a container to only apply to that particular container.

Is that possible w React? How are react developers supposed to handle container specific stylings? Do I need to add an ID to all containers and include that in the entire CSS file?

Comment: Read up on https://survivejs.com/react/advanced-techniques/styling-react/

Comment: https://medium.com/@pioul/modular-css-with-react-61638ae9ea3e

Comment: CSS always applies to the entire DOM. Components do not have a `body` element on their own, so of course this style would apply to the `body` element of the real DOM when loaded. You can either give your components unique class names and use that classes to style them or you can use the inline style approach as already suggested. Both have their benefits and disadvantages. There is a lot of discussion going on at the moment about this.

Comment: Is there a way for the component to apply an ID or Class to the Layout?

Comment: Yes sure there is. You can pass classes via the [`className` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#classname) to any jsx element. If you pass it to components they have to take care themselfs on which jsx elements they have to be applied.

Comment: Annoying problem that I think that react should set up

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Solution: Give your DOM elements class names to use them in your css.

JS:

```js
// in Link.js

import React from 'react';

import '../../styles/Link.css'

const Link = ({children, href}) => (
   <a className="link" href={href}>{children}</a>
);
```

CSS:

```js
// Link.css

.link {
    color: red;
}
```

### 2. Solution: Inline styles.

JS:

```js
// in Link.js

import React from 'react';

import '../../styles/Link.css'

const Link = ({children, href}) => (
   <a style={color: 'red'} href={href}>{children}</a>
);
```

### 3. Solution: CSS in JS.

There are some libraries that try to solve the styling issue:

Watch this talk: https://speakerdeck.com/vjeux/react-css-in-js

And have a look at this: https://github.com/cssinjs

styled-components: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest solution is to give classNames to every element you have in your code. I had the same issue when trying to apply widths and heights to my images and eventually found out that it was affecting whole app.