# how to stop react router using each other css or how to make each js file use their own css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, css-loader

I am very confuse about it, tried everything from `css` to `css module` to change file structure but none worked.

**My question is how to use completely different css in any js file without affecting React route, like use `body` in my case.**

I have a simple file structure like this.

```
 --index.js
 --home.js
 --home.css(i change to home.module.css)
 --login.js
 --login.css(i also change to login.module.css
```

problem is when I use `'body'` element in `login.css` and add to `login.js` it effect home.js to, I not import it to home, I use `home.css` to `home.js` but it get css from `login.css`.

Here are my file contents.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app'

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './homeStyle.module.css'


function Home() {
    return (
        <button className={styles.button}>This button</button>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

**login.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from './login.module.css'
import Home from './home'
import { Redirect, Link, Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
function Login() {
    return (
        <div className={styles.App}>
            <div>
                <p>ABC UNI</p>
                <p>Online Testing</p>
                <h1>LOGIN</h1>
            </div>

            <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                <i className="z"></i>
            </div>

            <div className={styles.inputContainer2}>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                <i className="z"></i>
                <Link to='/home'>
                    <button type='button'>Login</button>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login
```

My `login.css` and `home.css` have 2 `'body'` element.

**login.css**

```
 body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:left;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

**home.css**

```
 .button{
    background: fixed;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
}
body{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thi, after all the css is compiled to one global name space. That is why the style from one component is applied to the other. css in js or inline styles are the way to go. look at the following post for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989159/in-react-how-to-prevent-a-components-css-import-from-applying-to-the-entire-ap?rq=1

Comment: that exactly what i  need, thank you thousand time ^^

Comment: Possible SEO - "React Css showing although component not rendered"